# Using offsets into the buffer in PyOpenGL calls

Tags: python, numpy, opengl, ctypes, pyopengl

In OpenGL the *`indices`* parameter for [`glDrawElements`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual/glDrawElements.3G.html) has two different meanings, depending on if you are using `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` or not.

If you have a VBO bound, then it is the offset to start in that buffer, rather than the buffer itself.

When using PyOpenGL, how can you specify the offset to start at in a `glDrawElements` call?  How can you specify multiple start offsets in a `glMultiDrawElements` call?

Comment: By the way, `GL_INDEX_ARRAY` has a completely different meaning (per vertex color indices). What you mean is `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`

Comment: yeah I make that typo a thousand times

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11132716/how-to-specify-buffer-offset-with-pyopengl

Answer (score 0):

In the following examples a list of 6 indices is used, which may form a quad which consists of 2 triangle primitives.

```py
indices = [0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3]
```

Since the data which is passed to the OpenGL functions has to consist of fixed size units in a coherent buffer, the list of values has to be stored to an array of floats.
Coherent array buffers can be created either by [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) library or [`numpy.array`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) library.
The type of the array elements has to match value type enumerator constant, which is set, at the call of `glDrawElements` or `glMultiDrawElements`:

```
ctypes.c_ubyte   /  numpy.uint8     <->    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE
ctypes.c_ushort  /  numpy.uint16    <->    GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT
ctypes.c_uint    /  numpy.uint32    <->    GL_UNSIGNED_INT
```

Using `ctypes`:

```py
import ctypes

indexArray = (ctypes.c_uint * 6)(*indices)
```

Using `numpy`:

```py
import numpy

indexArray = numpy.array(indices, dtype=numpy.uint32)
```

For using an index buffer and [`glDrawElements`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawElements.xhtml) there are different opportunities.

Using [Legacy OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL) ([compatibility profile xontext](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context)), the buffer can be directly passed to `glDrawElements`. The pointer to the array data is passed to the function.

```py
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indexArray)
```

If named element array buffer object is stated in the vertex array object, then the last parameter of `glDrawElements` is treated as a byte offset into the buffer object's data store.

```py
glBindVertexArray(vao)

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo)
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexArray, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
```

If the indices should be drawn, starting at the 1st element of the buffer, then the last parameter can be `None`, which is equivalent to `ctypes.c_void_p(0)`:

```py
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, None)
```

If the drawing should not start with the first index, then the byte offset of the start index has to be calculated. e.g. `3*4` sets the start to the 3 index, for a buffer of type `GL_UNSIGNED_INT`:

```py
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, ctypes.c_void_p(3 * 4))
```

The use of [`glMultiDrawElements`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glMultiDrawElements.xhtml) is very similar.

Using a [compatibility profile xontext](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context), the buffer pointers can be directly passed to the OpenGL function.

To arrays of indices have to be generated:

Using `ctypes`:

```py
indexArray1 = (ctypes.c_uint * 3)(0, 1, 2)
indexArray2 = (ctypes.c_uint * 3)(0, 2, 3)
```

Using `numpy`:

```py
indexArray1 = numpy.array([0, 1, 2], dtype=numpy.uint32)
indexArray2 = numpy.array([0, 2, 3], dtype=numpy.uint32)
```

The pointers to the buffers have to be arranged to an array of pointers:

Using `ctypes` the pointer to the index data arrays is get by [`ctypes.addressof()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.addressof):

```py
indexPtr = (ctypes.c_void_p * 2)(ctypes.addressof(indexArray1),ctypes.addressof(indexArray2))
```

Using `numpy` the pointer to the index data arrays is get by [`numpy.ndarray.ctypes`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ctypes.html):

```py
indexPtr = numpy.array([indexArray1.ctypes.data, indexArray2.ctypes.data], dtype=numpy.intp)
```

This array of pointer can be passed to the OpenGL function:

```py
counts   = [3, 3]
glMultiDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, counts, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indexPtr, 2)
```

If a vertex array object with an named element array buffer is used,

```py
glBindVertexArray(vao)
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo)
```

then the index parameter is treated as a pointer to an array of byte offsets. In the following an array with 2 offset is passed to the function. 0 identifies the 1st index in the array and 3*4 the 3rd index.

Using `ctypes`:

```py
indexPtr = (ctypes.c_void_p * 2)(0, 3 * 4)
counts   = [3, 3]
glMultiDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, counts, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indexPtr, 2)
```

Using `numpy`:

```py
indexPtr = np.array([0, 3*4], dtype=numpy.intp)
counts   = [3, 3]
glMultiDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, counts, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indexPtr, 2)
```