# How to specify buffer offset with PyOpenGL

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl, vertex-buffer

What is the PyOpenGL equivalent of

```
#define BUFFER_OFFSET(i) (reinterpret_cast<void*>(i))

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, count, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, BUFFER_OFFSET(offset))
```

If the offset is 0, then

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, count, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, None)
```

works, but I can not figure out how to specify a non-zero offset into a buffer object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're supposed to pass a `ctypes` void pointer, which can constructed by :

```
ctypes.c_void_p(offset)
```

There seems to be a more PyOpenGL specific option using a `VBO` class, and gotcha with some versions of PyOpenGL according to [this](http://www.digipedia.pl/usenet/thread/16013/403/).

Comment: This is the same for glVertexAttribPointer - for anybody trying to get this working.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [OpenGL.arrays.vbo.VBO](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/pydoc/OpenGL.arrays.vbo.html) class for that:

```
from OpenGL.arrays import vbo

# data for your buffer
buf = vbo.VBO( [ 1,2,3,4,5,...], target = GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER ) 

# calls glBindBuffer
buf.bind() 

# starts reading at 14-th byte
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, count, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, buf + 14)
```