# OpengL Where is my square?

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

I cannot figure out why the glDrawElements is not working. I've used the glDrawArrays successfully. But the moment I try to draw with glDrawElements, it is not working.

I am following the learnopengl.com website's tutorials in python, so it adds a bit to the headache. Any idea why this is not working? I've been looking at it for almost a day and can't see the error in my ways.

```
import glfw
import numpy as np
import OpenGL

from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GL import shaders, ArrayDatatype
from ctypes import sizeof, c_float, c_void_p

def main():
    width = 800
    height = 600
    title = 'Hello Triangle'

    vertex = """#version 410 core
        in vec3 aPos;
        void main() {
            gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
        }"""
    fragment = """#version 410 core
        out vec4 FragColor;
        void main() {
            FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.5, 0.2, 1.0);
        }"""

    if not glfw.init():
        raise TypeError('Unable to initalize glfw')

    glfw.window_hint(glfw.SAMPLES, 4)
    glfw.window_hint(glfw.CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4)
    glfw.window_hint(glfw.CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 1)
    glfw.window_hint(glfw.OPENGL_PROFILE, glfw.OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE)
    glfw.window_hint(glfw.OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, True)
    glfw.window_hint(glfw.OPENGL_DEBUG_CONTEXT, True)

    window = glfw.create_window(width, height, title, None, None)
    if not window:
        raise TypeError('Unable to create the window')
    glfw.make_context_current(window)
    glfw.set_framebuffer_size_callback(window, framebuffer_size)

    verts = np.array([[-0.5, 0.5, 0.0], [-0.5, -0.5, 0.0], [0.5, -0.5, 0.0], [0.5, 0.5, 0.0]], dtype=np.float)
    indices = np.array([[0, 1, 3], [3, 1, 2]], dtype=np.uint)

    vertex_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
    glShaderSource(vertex_shader, vertex)
    glCompileShader(vertex_shader)

    fragment_shader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
    glShaderSource(fragment_shader, fragment)
    glCompileShader(fragment_shader)

    shader_program = glCreateProgram()
    glAttachShader(shader_program, vertex_shader)
    glAttachShader(shader_program, fragment_shader)
    glLinkProgram(shader_program)

    glDeleteShader(vertex_shader)
    glDeleteShader(fragment_shader)

    vao_id = glGenVertexArrays(1)
    vbo_id = glGenBuffers(1)
    ebo_id = glGenBuffers(1)

    glBindVertexArray(vao_id)

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo_id)
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
    #glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_id)
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verts, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, False, 0, None)
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)

    #glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)

    #glBindVertexArray(0)

    while not glfw.window_should_close(window):
        glClearColor(0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

        glUseProgram(shader_program)
        glBindVertexArray(vao_id)
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
        #glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4)
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0)
        glBindVertexArray(0)

        glfw.swap_interval(1)
        glfw.swap_buffers(window)
        glfw.poll_events()

    glfw.destroy_window(window)
    glfw.terminate()

def framebuffer_size(window, width, height):
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two tricky issues that need to be addressed in this code, and both of them are subtle and python-specific.

First, you should replace the `0` in `glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0)` with `None`. I suspect this is because PyOpenGL uses ctypes to wrap OpenGL and `None` is recommended to represent the `NULL` pointer according to the [ctypes documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#calling-functions). If you need to use offsets for your buffers later, you should look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11132716/2588654).

Second, if you just do step 1 and run the code, you might find the output to not be what you expect:

[image]

What happened to our orange rectangle? Well, the problem here is with the data we are passing to our buffer objects. If you are on a 64-bit device, the numpy data types (dtype) will be 64-bit too if not fully specified. OpenGL expects 32-bit floats and integers rather than doubles, so we need to use `np.float32` instead. I would also use `np.uint32` for your index buffer for consistency's sake, but this is not strictly necessary. If we fix your `verts` and `indices` initialization statements to this:

```
verts = np.array([[-0.5, 0.5, 0.0], [-0.5, -0.5, 0.0], [0.5, -0.5, 0.0], [0.5, 0.5, 0.0]], dtype=np.float32)
indices = np.array([[0, 1, 3], [3, 1, 2]], dtype=np.uint32)
```

The results should be more like what you expect:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: @AdamAdamAdam Glad it helped. If you go through all of these learnopengl tutorials, maybe you can put all of the final code on github for each tutorial if you get the chance? I suspect that it would be useful for others who will likely run into similar issues (I know I definitely did the first time around).

Comment: This was my intent. Go through all the hard parts and post the code on github.