# How to specify indices as void * to glDrawElements with PyQt5 OpenGL

Tags: python, opengl, pyqt5, python-sip

I want to call glDrawElements on the same element buffer object more than once, where each draw call accesses different parts of the element buffer object. So, out of many ways possible, in C/C++, one of them was to set the `void * indices` argument. I tried a similar thing in PyQt5 using QOpenGLWidget, but I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/to/dir/scratch.py", line 305, in paintGL
    self.renderer.draw(self.m_gl)
  File "path/to/dir/scratch.py", line 257, in draw
    obj.drawCall(gl)
  File "path/to/dir/scratch.py", line 217, in drawCall
    gl.glDrawElements(gl.GL_TRIANGLES, 3, self.idxdtype, 2) # tri2.
TypeError: glDrawElements(self, int, int, int, PYQT_OPENGL_ARRAY): array must be a sequence or a buffer
```

What does the type `PYQT_OPENGL_ARRAY` mean? I cannot seem to find any hints [here](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/opengl.html) or on SO. Whereas [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11132716/how-to-specify-buffer-offset-with-pyopengl) post looks like a possible duplicate, the question firstly refers to PyOpenGL and besides the suggested answer `ctypes.c_void_p(int)` gives the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/to/dir/scratch.py", line 305, in paintGL
    self.renderer.draw(self.m_gl)
  File "path/to/dir/scratch.py", line 257, in draw
    obj.drawCall(gl)
  File "path/to/dir/scratch.py", line 217, in drawCall
    gl.glDrawElements(gl.GL_TRIANGLES, 3, self.idxdtype, ctypes.c_void_p(2)) # tri2.
TypeError: a 1-dimensional buffer is required
```

The draw call looks like this. I am aware that I can directly use the entire element buffer to draw the two triangles, but I want to be able to use this functionality of `void * indices`

```
    def drawCall(self, gl):
        self.shaderProgram.bind()
        self.vao.bind()
        self.shaderProgram.setUniformValue(self.u_ColorIdx, self.color)
        self.shaderProgram.setUniformValue(self.u_MVPidx, self.mvpMatrix)

        # tri1 would be in the y-ve region and colored red.
        gl.glDrawElements(gl.GL_TRIANGLES, 3, self.idxdtype, None) # tri1
        # tri2 would be in the y+ve region and colored green.
        self.shaderProgram.setUniformValue(self.u_ColorIdx, QtGui.QVector4D(0.0, 0.7, 0.3, 1.0))
        gl.glDrawElements(gl.GL_TRIANGLES, 3, self.idxdtype, ctypes.c_void_p(2)) # tri2.

        # I am aware that I might as well rotate tri1 by 180 degrees around z-axis, 
        # and set u_color uniform value to green to achieve the desired effect. But I want
        # to do it using indices. It seems better for a large number of objects.

        self.shaderProgram.release()
        self.vao.release()
```

Finally, a link to the entire example [code](https://github.com/jaswantp/pyqt5IdxBuf.git).

Edit: I am not looking for answers that suggest the usage of PyOpenGL/ModernGL to set the buffer objects.

Comment: There seems to be a difference between *PyQt5* and  [*PyOpenGL*](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/). The code works when using *PyOpenGL* (it can be used additionally to *PyQt5*)

Comment: So, that's the only alternative? It's surprising. I wanted to use PyQt5's OpenGL bindings to avoid a context mess. Is it the way to go?

Comment: I don't know. In my opinion you should never use OpenGL instructions directly in Qt. e.g. use `QOpenGLBuffer.VertexBuffer`. Anyway,  `PYQT_OPENGL_ARRAY` is defines as `PYQT_OPENGL_ARRAY = typing.Union[typing.Sequence[int], typing.Sequence[float], sip.Buffer, None]`. See [pyqt/python-qt5](https://github.com/pyqt/python-qt5/blob/master/PyQt5/Qsci.pyi)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that. I searched a lot and could not find it, perhaps I just didn't know where to look. I tried `gl.glDrawElements(gl.GL_TRIANGLES, 3, self.idxdtype, [3])` but that doesn't help. As far as `sip.Buffer`, I couldn't find any documentation that explains its usage. I hold the same opinion and do not want to mix another OpenGL library's calls within Qt, hence trying to stay away from doing that.

Comment: It would help if anyone can explain the usage of  `PYQT_OPENGL_ARRAY` or `sip.Buffer`. I am absolutely clueless about this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and finally found a solution using numpy.ndarray.tolist().

> glf.glTexImage2D(glf.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, glf.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,
> self._images[i].shape[1], self._images[i].shape[0], 0,
> glf.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, glf.GL_FLOAT,
> self._images[i].flatten().tolist())