# glVertexPointer(), glNormalPointer - stride and pointer parameters in PyOpenGL

Tags: python, opengl, vbo, pyopengl

I am using interleaved `VBO` to display geometry using Python and PyOpenGL. The VBO consists of vertices, normals and colors:

```
[vx1, vy1, vz1, nx1, ny1, nz1, R1, G1, B1, vx2...]
```

Drawing is made with the code:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY)
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY)
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo_id)

v_pointer = None
n_pointer = ctypes.c_void_p(12)
c_pointer = ctypes.c_void_p(24)

v_stride = 24
n_stride = 24
c_stride = 24

glVertexPointer(3, 
                GL_FLOAT, 
                v_stride, 
                v_pointer)
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT,
                n_stride,
                n_pointer)
glColorPointer(3,
               GL_FLOAT,
               c_stride,
               c_pointer)

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,      #POINTS
             0,
             self.len_)
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0) # reset
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY)
glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY)
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
```

The displayed geometry should be a simple cube but all I get is randomly oriented triangles (see figure). I was reading about the `glVertexPointer()` problems in PyOpenGL [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431103/using-offsets-into-the-buffer-in-pyopengl-calls?rq=1) and found the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11132716/how-to-specify-buffer-offset-with-pyopengl?rq=1) with `ctypes.c_void_p()` but I am not really sure how to implement it. Can someone point out what am I doing wrong or missing here? Or how can I fix this?

Based on the [documentation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glVertexPointer.xml) the `stride` parameter is offset between 2 consecutive arrays of the same type (vertices, normals, colors...) (in bytes) in `VBO` array. Or not?

[image: drawn triagles]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem about normals. The code is:

```
    v_pointer = ctypes.c_void_p(0)   # or None
    n_pointer = ctypes.c_void_p(12)
    c_pointer = ctypes.c_void_p(24)

    v_stride = 36
    n_stride = 36
    c_stride = 36
```

But I still have problems with colors as the model is not colorful? :) Any ideas are much appreciated.